# Why curvature produced by electric field in spacetime is so small?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

The electric field due to charge is $E=\frac{Q}{r^2}$. Why is the curvature in spacetime produced by this electric field so small?

Let's say we want to calculate curvature(in spacetime) produced by the electron's electric field? What will be its magnitude?

Comment: Your first question seems to presuppose an answer to the second...

Comment: Hi Gary, One single electron won't do much, that for sure, so if you leave it at one electron you will have answered your own question. Maybe you should choose something much bigger, like How much curvature is produced by the electromagnetic field of the Sun.  Sorry @Danu, crossed

Comment: You'll have to calculate the electromagnetic field strength's contribution to the stress-energy tensor to see if and what kind of "curvature" this electric field produces. Asking about such calculations, however, is off-topic as *homework-like*.

Comment: In any case, one should do some Google searches related to "Reissner-Nordström" solutions of the Einstein field equations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Nordström spacetime:

$$ds^{2} = - f dt^{2} + \frac{1}{f}dr^{2} + r^{2}d\theta^{2} + r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}$$

where $f = 1 - 2M/r + Q^{2}/r^{2}$, in units where $G = c =1$ and Gaussian units are chosen for the electric charge.

While it's unclear what you mean by "curvature" since, generically, the curvature of this metric is a tensor with many components, the net radial force felt by a particle will be:

$$F = -\frac{1}{2}f = -M/r^{2} + Q^{2}/r^{3}$$

Comment: One meaning of the word curvature is the highest curvature in any direction at a point. In fact that's the usual meaning.

Comment: To clarify - when you say net radial force you mean on an uncharged particle.

Comment: @TomAndersen  I think that since the Q (electric charge) variable is included, and it is the Nordström metric, the force equation applies to a charged particle, also the OP specifically mentions an electron.

Comment: @AcidJazz: no, this is the force on an uncharged particle.  For a charged particle, we'd have to also consider the electric field at the point, which I did not include.

Comment: @TomAndersen: yes, you are correct.